# Magento 2 - Cart Page - Exception #0 (Exception): Item (Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item) with the same ID "0" already exists

Tags: magento-2.3

I have keep getting error when I am adding product to cart and Navigate to Cart page.

I am running mangento 2 in dev domain in Siteground host. I have tried to truncate all quote tables even its showing me same error.

Much appreciate if someone give me direction to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of issue generally occur when your table is corrupted or auto increment is removed from primary index column.
Check your table fields by "DESCRIBE QUOTE", Is auto increment set or not? if there is primary key set (which require unique value) but auto increment is missing. that could be the reason of error: the same id “0” already exist.